# Media Library images are not showing and not uploading in Wordpress . I got this error " An error occurred while sending. Please try again later."

Tags: wordpress

[image: Wordpress error screenshot]

Media Library images are not showing  and not uploading in Wordpress . I got this error  " An error occurred while sending. Please try again later."

Comment: Need more information from your logs.

Comment: In log file .I  am not getting any error.

Comment: Can you share the file name? Wordpress is not allowing space and some special characters.

Comment: @AkshayShah media-new.php

Comment: My mistake. Image file name pls

Comment: @AkshayShah ajax-loader.gif